# Android: перехват массива кнопок

Tags: массивы, android, java

Как перехватить массив кнопок?

Вот это не работает =(

```
  @Override
     public void onClick(View view)
     {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
          if(view == close_tab[i])
          {
            buy_name[i].setText("");
            buy_cost[i].setText("");
            buy_many[i].setText("");

            buy_name[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buy_cost[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buy_many[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);

            field_count -= 1;
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что это за кусок кода вырванный из контекста? Добавьте остальной код. Вы клик как присваиваете кнопке?

Чтобы перехватывать несколько кнопок и делать уникальные действия нужно проверять каждую кнопку по id если используете один и тот же метод-обработчика для нее.

```
if( view.getId() == R.id.my_super_button ){
     //do something
}
```

Добавьте кнопкам событие onClick в xml: android:onClick, вытащите кнопки через findViewById() добавьте их в список (ArrayList) и по циклу ставьте невидимость.

Также, вызывает сомнение правильность решения использовать тьму кнопок. Думаю что-то Вы не то делаете.